# Talyor series representation of $Ln(z)$ centered at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is question from applied complex variables.

Let $P(z)$ : talyor series representation of $Ln(z)$ centered at $z_0 =-1-i$. And let the radius of convergence $R$.

Explain why following is not true : $Ln(z)$=$P(z)$ whenever $|z-z_0|<R$.

My attempt : Since $Ln(z)$ is analytic except {$(x+0i)$ | $x \leq0$ }, radius of convergence = 1.

Then, $Ln$(z) is analytic where $|z-z_0|<1$. So taylor series expansion applies.

But, taylor series implies that series expansion equals $Ln(z)$ where $|z-z_0|<1$.

What did I missed?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. In particular, what do you mean by $Ln(z)$? You can certainly extend the logarithm to an analytic function on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-z_0| < \sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: @Klaus $Ln(z)=log(|z|)+Arg(z) i$ is not analytic at non-positive real numbers. So I thought it is analytic on $|z - z_0 |<1$. Is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: It all depends on your definitions, which is why I mentioned that your question is unclear. From what you wrote I infer that your $Arg(z)$ takes values in $(-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: @Klaus Actually, ($-\pi , \pi$]

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed right that $P(z) = \mathrm{Ln}(z)$ for $|z-z_0| < 1$. But the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is actually $\sqrt{2}$. This is because $\mathrm{Ln}(z)$ can be analytically extended beyond the ray of negative real numbers, but it will be multi-valued. To see this, consider the function $\widetilde{\mathrm{Ln}}$, which we define to be the inverse of
$$\exp: \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Im}(z) \in (-2\pi,0)\} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0\}.$$
As the inverse of an analytic function $\widetilde{\mathrm{Ln}}$ will be analytic as well. Moreover, it has to coincide with $\mathrm{Ln}$ on $\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} : x < 0, y < 0\}$ by the uniqueness of inverses. The Taylor series of $\mathrm{Ln}$ and $\widetilde{\mathrm{Ln}}$ are thus the same in $z_0$. But as $\widetilde{\mathrm{Ln}}$ is analytic on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-z_0| < \sqrt{2}\}$, the radius of convergence is (at least) $\sqrt{2}$. Since $\mathrm{Ln}$ is discontinuous at the negative real numbers, it follows that the Taylor series does not coincide with $\mathrm{Ln}$ for $1 < |z-z_0| < \sqrt{2}$, $\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0$.

To summarize: The radius of convergence of a Taylor series can be larger than the domain of definition of an analytic function.

Comment: the answer has an incorrect statement since the taylor series coincides with Ln at $z=-3i/2$ where $1<|z-z_0| <\sqrt 2$; where it fails to coincide is when $\Im z >0$ and $|z-z_0| < \sqrt 2$

Comment: @Conrad True, I meant for $\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0$ of course, I'll edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=Ln(z)$ is defined on the open set $U=\mathbb C -\mathbb R_-$ while $P(z)$, the Taylor series of it, at $z_0=-1-i$ is defined on the open set $V$ given by $|z-z_0| < \sqrt 2$ as one can easily see by taking derivatives which are just $\pm z_0^{-n}(n-1)!$ and finding the radius of convergence to be $|z_0|=\sqrt 2$.

By analytic continuation $f(z)=P(z)$ whenver $z \in W$ the connected component of $U \cap V$ containing $z_0$ hence for $|z-z_0| < \sqrt 2, \Im z <0$ which is the description of $W$ seen by drawing a picture.

However, there is no guarantee that $f=P$ outside $W$ even if both are defined there, only that $f-P$ is constant (multiple of $2\pi i$ of course) on $W_1$ = $U \cap V -W$ (which has description$|z-z_0| < \sqrt 2, \Im z >0$) and indeed by continuity $\Im P$ is $-\pi$ on the negative imaginary axis hence slighly above where defined it will be $-\pi -\epsilon$, while $\Im f$ is $\pi -\epsilon$ there so on $W_1$ we have $f-P=2\pi i$